# Problema al seleccionar múltiple rating

Tags: css, html5

Estoy intentando manejar dentro de un formulario un rating pero estoy presentando el problema de que al seleccionar cualquier item diferente al primero siempre se me queda marcado el primer item, comparto en un snipper el codigo hmtl y css

```css
.rating {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50%;*/
  /*left: 50%;*/
  transform: translate( 0, -40%) rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
}

.rating input {
    display: none;
}

.rating label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45px;

}

.rating label:before {
   content: '\f005';
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: lightgray;
}

.rating label:after {
   content: '\f005';
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: black;
   top: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .5s;
   text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating label:hover:after,
.rating label:hover ~ label:after,
.rating input:checked ~ label:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"><label for="star5" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"><label for="star4" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"><label for="star3" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"><label for="star2" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"><label for="star1" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"><label for="star5" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"><label for="star4" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"><label for="star3" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"><label for="star2" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"><label for="star1" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"><label for="star5" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"><label for="star4" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"><label for="star3" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"><label for="star2" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"><label for="star1" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>                                          
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"><label for="star5" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"><label for="star4" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"><label for="star3" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"><label for="star2" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"><label for="star1" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas que evitan que tu **rating** funcione correctamente:

- Si deseas que cada **rating** funcione independientemente (que pueda haber varios de ellos seleccionados a la vez) debes darles diferente atributo **name**. Si no se comportarán como si fuesen parte del mismo grupo por lo que tan solo podrá haber un **rating** marcado simultáneamente.
- Para evitar que solamente te funcione el primero debes usar diferentes **IDs** en tus `<input type="radio">`. Recuerda que en tu **HTML** el **ID** de tus elementos debe ser único, sin compartirse con otros.
- El atributo **for** de los `<label>` asociados a cada `<input type="radio">` debe apuntar al **ID** nuevo tras el cambio de **IDs** del paso anterior.

```css
.rating {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50%;*/
  /*left: 50%;*/
  transform: translate( 0, -40%) rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
}

.rating input {
    display: none;
}

.rating label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45px;

}

.rating label:before {
   content: '\f005';
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: lightgray;
}

.rating label:after {
   content: '\f005';
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: black;
   top: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .5s;
   text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating label:hover:after,
.rating label:hover ~ label:after,
.rating input:checked ~ label:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo1" id="star5"><label for="star5" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo1" id="star4"><label for="star4" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo1" id="star3"><label for="star3" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo1" id="star2"><label for="star2" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo1" id="star1"><label for="star1" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo2" id="star10"><label for="star10" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo2" id="star9"><label for="star9" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo2" id="star8"><label for="star8" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo2" id="star7"><label for="star7" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stagrupo2r" id="star6"><label for="star6" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo3" id="star15"><label for="star15" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo3" id="star14"><label for="star14" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo3" id="star13"><label for="star13" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo3" id="star12"><label for="star12" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo3" id="star11"><label for="star11" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>                                          
  </br></br>
                                        
  <li class="list-group-item">
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo4" id="star20"><label for="star20" title="5 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo4" id="star19"><label for="star19" title="4 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo4" id="star18"><label for="star18" title="3 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo4" id="star17"><label for="star17" title="2 estrellas"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="stargrupo4" id="star16"><label for="star16" title="1 estrella"></label>
</div>
</br>
  </li>
  </br></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Todos tus grupos de radios se llaman "star". Cambia el atributo "name", cada grupo debe tener un "name" distinto.